# Magneto 2.3 SMTP configured but mails not send

Tags: magento2, smtp, m2e

after setting up SMTP extension ,when send test mail giving error "Unable to send mail:unknown error" and
in exception log gives bellow exception.

> " main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail: Unknown error
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send
> mail: Unknown error at
> /var/www/magento/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Transport.php:104,
> Laminas\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable
> to send mail: Unknown error at
> /var/www/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:306)"}
> [] "

what would be the reason, and how could I get out of this.. Thank you.

Comment: login with proper gmail password and id

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the SMTP parameters ?
Theh, checklist :
1st  : Can you send the transactional emails ?
2nd : your server configuration. Is it a VPS ? a dedicated server ? is it Linux based or Windows ? postfix up & running ? credentials ?